# Angular 2 Http Service GET with body

Tags: json, angular, http, request

I want to use a body in my GET request. I am not finding any way to do it with Angular 2/4.

I Found the `body` attribute in the `RequestOptionsArgs` class, but it is not sending in the http request.

With `httpie.org` it's possible to send it like this :

`http --verbose GET 'http://localhost/api/test' 'Content-Type: application/json' 'foo=bar'`

This is sending this raw request:

```js
GET /api/test HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 14
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.9
enter code here
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

```js
this.http.get("/api/test", {body: JSON.stringify{foo: "bar"}})
```

Comment: You cannot do that in angular2/4

Comment: Need conclusion please

Comment: By using Angular 2/4 you cannot send body.   in general   you can send a request body with GET but it should not have any meaning. If you give it meaning by parsing it on the server and changing your response based on its contents, then you are ignoring this recommendation in the HTTP/1.1 spec, section 4.3:

Comment: Ty ! great response ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using Angular 2/4 you cannot send body. in general you can send a request body with GET but it should not have any meaning. If you give it meaning by parsing it on the server and changing your response based on its contents, then you are ignoring this recommendation in the HTTP/1.1 spec, section 4.3

Comment: how is it possible?

Comment: the latest update to HTTP1.1 RFC removed that clause about shouldn't have meaning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: There are changes in Angular to support this?